# Angular - TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, button, disable

I'm trying to change a property of an object of an array. The property is false by default and I'd like to change it to true if a button is clicked. And  then make a button disabled if this property is true. I've got this error: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined.

cart.component.ts

```
purchaseDisabled(product:Product){
    product.purchased=true;
  }
```

Card.component.ts

```
purchasedProduct(){
      if(this.productItem.purchased=true){
        this.buttonDisabled = true;
      }

    }
```

Comment: The error means that either `product` or `this.productItem` is undefined.

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, `==` or `===` is what you should use to check condition

Comment: `this.productItem` seems to be `undefined`

Comment: You are assigning a value in if condition instead you should check wether it's true or not, so check if(this.productItem.purchased.includes(true)){ // your logic }

Comment: Looks like product is undefined and not this.productItem. How can I make sure it won't throw an error of undefined? @AmanJha and Konrad you are right, corrected it thanks.

Comment: your 1st function not doing anything. please make it clear that where you're getting undefined error

Comment: @Exception I try to set the purchased property of product to true in the 1st function if a specific button is clicked: (click)="purchaseDisabled()". If it's not doing anything, how can I make it?

Comment: In 1st method you are assigning true to some thing which you get it from method argument, it doesn't mean anything to compiler

Comment: You can use safeNavigation operator in Angular, which helps you in avoid undefined scenarios and your app flow will not be interrupted.
like: - this.productItem?.purchased
link to complete use guide : https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-pipe-operator-and-safe-navigation-operator-example#:~:text=Safe%20navigation%20operator%20(%20%3F.%20),object%20is%20null%20or%20undefined.